# How do I omit the default text at the start of my output video

Tags: animation, video

When I click Animate my video for output, the rendered video had a text title on it, such as Video 1-1429-2584. I do not want any text at all - just the video that I built. How do I turn this off?

Comment: Please clarify your question by including a Blender screen snapshot.  Show relevant windows that address your situation.  Please do so in the future always.

Comment: This can happen if you have accidentally checked 'Stamp Output' in the metadata section of the render tab in the properties editor.

Comment: What’s the betting it is the video player? ;)